# c# application stopped working System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

After I publish my application in Visual Studio 2015 and put the publish files on the remote server, I keep getting the following error:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: Personeel.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 58fdcdf8
  Problem Signature 04: System.Data
  Problem Signature 05: 4.6.1055.0
  Problem Signature 06: 563c13ab
  Problem Signature 07: 2599
  Problem Signature 08: 5d
  Problem Signature 09: System.InvalidOperationException
  OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.16.7
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 74ac
  Additional Information 2: 74acff91be3a79a847a4c136374196b5
  Additional Information 3: ff07
  Additional Information 4: ff07fc8188fb2691835f1a2bee1f0e1f

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=280262

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Afterwards I can only close the application and nothing is working. The strange thing is that the exact same code is working on the old remote server (older version not 2012 MS). I checked multiple times the .net framework is 4.5.2 and it is set to support any cpu (which is what is supported by other application also made by me on the server).

I've been stuck on this for a while now and some help would be appreciated!

< Update >

```
Application: Personeel.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbServicesWrapper.GetDataSource(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionString, System.Data.OleDb.DataSourceWrapper ByRef)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionString, System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionPoolKey, System.Object, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool, System.Data.Common.DbConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPoolGroup, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1<System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal>, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal ByRef)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1<System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal>, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
   at Lemerij.Repository.LemerijRepository.openConnections()
   at Lemerij.Repository.LemerijRepository..ctor()
   at Personeel.Presenter.HomePresenter.loadMedewerkers()
   at Personeel.Presenter.HomePresenter..ctor(Personeel.View.Home)
   at Personeel.View.Home..ctor()
   at Personeel.Program.Main()
```

**Error 2**

```
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: CLR20r3
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: Personeel.exe
P2: 1.0.0.0
P3: 58fde3b6
P4: System.Data
P5: 4.6.1055.0
P6: 563c13ab
P7: 2599
P8: 5d
P9: System.InvalidOperationException
P10: 

Attached files:

These files may be available here:
C:\Users\adminjm\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_Personeel.exe_38e793e1fc55b81cf5d8dd87c6ca47643294bd9f_3b8a8d3f_20d7d235

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: d8ff9f36-28e2-11e7-8178-000c293bf429
Report Status: 2048
Hashed bucket:
```

**Error 3:**

```
Faulting application name: Personeel.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x58fde3b6
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.18202, time stamp: 0x569e7eb1
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x0000000000008a5c
Faulting process id: 0x11d4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d2bcef9b236481
Faulting application path: C:\Users\adminjm\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\O4ONW6JV.BT5\T7KCVD16.B8Y\pers..tion_7ca3505acee249c8_0001.0000_0d30d07889d3915c\Personeel.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: d8ff9f36-28e2-11e7-8178-000c293bf429
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

> 

Comment: Maybe post some code, no one can help you like this

Comment: Does debugging work ?

Comment: The program is about 205k lines, I doubt I would make anyone happy with that. The code is working fine as it is working on other computers/servers. It's just this specific situation that is not working.

Comment: Debugging works, however locally the system is running fine. I cannot debug on the server as it does not have VS.

Comment: @DennisMuller You need to get more than just the name of the error. Specifically, you need to obtain a stack trace to indicate where the error is occurring. Without this, you're shooting in the dark. Looking in eventviewer->application and look for errors with source ".net runtime". This might be the quickest way to obtain the stacktrace. Otherwise, get a bit of logging into your program and redeploy.

Comment: The "this only happens on one computer" argument is moot. It's still happening, and you still need to go through the normal diagnostic steps.

Comment: Alright, here is the full stack trace then, there is 3 errors prompting:

Comment: Due to space, it is updated in the original post, I thought I understood the error, however sadly I dont

Answer (score 0):

As others have said in the comments, we need to see some code to know for sure...

However the last call in your stack trace;

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbServicesWrapper.GetDataSource(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionString, System.Data.OleDb.DataSourceWrapper ByRef)
```

Suggests that the exception is being thrown by an OLEDB call... Since you said it works on one server but not the other - I would first check the user accounts used by both servers. I would guess they are different and the one that is not working does not have proper permissions for whatever Data Source your application is using (SQL permissions for database? File permissions for Excel/CSV file it reads?)

You could at the very least post the code for your 
Personeel.Presenter.HomePresenter.loadMedewerkers()
method as that seems to be the last place in your code that is calling some other things...

Did you try looking in the Event Log?? This should have the exception logged, hopefully with a more useful error message? But we really have to see some code to know what is going wrong...

Comment: Very well code is updated with the specific methods that should be required, code was small enough to upload! Thanks for the input anyway and as a final notice, the database is an MDB (access)

Comment: and the 3 errors posted are sadly the event logs from the server, I do not have any other stacktraces other than these. If this does not solve it I will have to build in a manual stacktrace

Comment: Wow, you have a whole load of connection strings there.... Are you sure you have the required drivers (I guess it would be Ace for access?) installed on both servers? Did you check the user accounts it is running under?

Comment: @Soldexio Maybe have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179905/the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine Similar error

Comment: The database was sadly made by someone without knowledge and the company does not want to change the structure so I have to work with what exists sadly. I will look into what you said, the drivers exist atleast since other applications that are running and working use the same connectionStrings

Comment: And to verify, users have full access to the databases as expected, since other applications use the same databases :)

Comment: @Soldexio They may however be built as X86 (32 bit apps) and if you have targeted AnyCPU and the server is 64bit then you need the 64 bit driver - As is mentioned in the question which I linked you. I would first check that - then the user accounts, can't be too much else since it is the OLEDB call that is failing

Comment: This is what is bothering me the most, there is 3 other applications running, which use the same connectionStrings and databases, these are working, but only in this specific application it is not working.

Comment: Alright, I'll try that one, definitely worth a shot, I'll update you shortly.

Comment: Dear god, thank you so much! It is indeed that any cpu is screwing things up here, accdb is 32 bit, the application was now run as 64 bit!

Comment: Good stuff - Yeah the OLEDB drivers are always a pain in the A**! Glad you got it sorted

Comment: Thank you Milney, really appreciated :)