# How to check if our connection is correct to Excel using C# (OLEDB)?

Tags: c#

So the following C# code contain the code that I use to check my database connection. Not sure whether it's the correct way or not but I seems to always get the:

> " System.InvalidOperationException: 'The Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine'

Any idea how to fix this? btw I'm currently using VS2017 and Excel 2016

```
try{
   string connectString = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source =C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Book1.xlsx;Extended Properties=\"Excel 16.0 XML;HDR=Yes;\"";

   OleDbConnection xlConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectString);
   xlConnection.Open();
   MessageBox.Show("Success");

   }
catch(OleDbExceptionEx ex)
   {
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   }
```

Comment: What is the exception you are catching?

Comment: You also seem to be missing a quotation mark from the end of the connection string.

Comment: Sorry I'm still quite new to this, what do you mean by that? Does the code check my connection?

Comment: It's still wrong though, my original code has the quotation mark in it, I just missed it here

Comment: When you call `xlConnection.Open()` it will throw an exception if it can't connect successfully. You are then catching this exception using the try-catch block. That exception contains details about why opening the connection failed. Change `catch` to `catch (OleDbException ex)` and add `MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)` to the block underneath it.

Comment: Ahh I see, now it state" System.InvalidOperationException: 'The Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine' Hmm is there a higher version than this then?

Comment: When you uncover new info to your problem it's best to edit your question, so others can see it asap, so make sure you add the exception message to your question :). As for the solution, check out  [the top answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179905/the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine). Here is the [official Microsoft thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64/how-to-fix-error-the-microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine?forum=vstsdb)

Comment: Try this at the end: `Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES\"`. And see in Control Panel - ODBC Data Sources.

Comment: @i486 Unfortunately, It doesn't work

Comment: See in Data Sources in Control Panel for Excel data source. Maybe you have to install ODBC source, or MS Office, or LibreOffice (which will install ODBC driver).

Comment: @i486 I fixed it by downloading this https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23734 Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score -1):

As per a comment conversion with Tamás:

The solution is in the [top answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179905/the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine). Here is the  [official Microsoft thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64/how-to-fix-error-the-microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine?forum=vstsdb).

So from the link that Tamás has provided, I manage to fix the my problem by downloading [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23734).

Comment: Did it fix the issue?

Comment: Also what i meant is you should edit your question, not add my comment as an answer.

Comment: @TamásSzabó It work! So can I still keep this answer here?

Comment: You should not (that is why you were downvoted). It's best to close your question, mark it as duplicate and provide a link to the question I linked you.

Comment: Sorry but I can't seems to close my own question could you help me with that? @TamásSzabó

Comment: Sorry, I got a little busy. Click [this](http://imgur.com/a/QZ9ak) button, choose 'Duplicate of' and provide the link.

Comment: It's fine. Yeah that's the problem, beside the edit button it's immediately delete. Should I just delete it? @TamásSzabó

Comment: As you gain more reputation you'll be able to do more stuff, but for now that's probably the easiest, yeah.