# Why am I obtaining this exception: "he 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine"?

Tags: c#, .net, oledb, oledbconnection, oledbexception

I have this simple **C#** console application:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ImporterRidistribuzioni
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ImporterRidistribuzioni START");

            string path = "C:\\WS\\RegoleInoltro\\TunnelPro-DistribuzioneTitolario.xlsx";

            ReadREgoleInoltroFrmExcelFile(path);

            Console.WriteLine("ImporterRidistribuzioni END");
        }


        public static void ReadREgoleInoltroFrmExcelFile(string filePath)
        {
            DataTable regoleInoltro;
            string oleDBConnectionString = GetOleDBConnectionString(filePath);

            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(oleDBConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                cmd.Connection = conn;

                // Get all Sheets in Excel File
                DataTable dtSheet = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

                /// Prendo il nome del primo foglio
                DataRow dr = dtSheet.Rows[0];
                string sheetName = dr["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();

                //regoleInoltro = GetDataTablePerimetro(cmd, sheetName);
                cmd = null;
                conn.Close();
            }
            //return regoleInoltro;
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that when it trys to perform this line:

```
conn.Open();
```

i obtain this exception: **"The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.**

Here the details:

```
-       $exception  {"The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine."} System.InvalidOperationException
+       Data    {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal} System.Collections.IDictionary {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
        HResult -2146233079 int
        HelpLink    null    string
+       InnerException  null    System.Exception
        Message "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine."   string
        Source  "System.Data"   string
        StackTrace  "   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbServicesWrapper.GetDataSource(OleDbConnectionString constr, DataSourceWrapper& datasrcWrapper)\r\n   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection)\r\n   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)\r\n   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()\r\n   at ImporterRidistribuzioni.Program.ReadREgoleInoltroFrmExcelFile(String filePath) in C:\\WS\\ArxeiaProtocollo2016\\ImporterRidistribuzioni\\Program.cs:line 32\r\n   at ImporterRidistribuzioni.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\\WS\\ArxeiaProtocollo2016\\ImporterRidistribuzioni\\Program.cs:line 19" string
+       TargetSite  {Void GetDataSource(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionString, System.Data.OleDb.DataSourceWrapper ByRef)}    System.Reflection.MethodBase {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}
```

I am working on a **Windows Server 2012** in Azure cloud.

I installed the 64 bit version of this tool: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

as suggested here: [The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179905/the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine)

but nothings change. I still obtain the same error.

Why? What am I missing? How can I try to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you double checked that you installed the correct version (64-bit or 32-bit)

Comment: @apomene I installed the 64 bit version

Comment: Is your console application build as 64bit? (Any CPU)

Comment: @apomene thank you man, if you pot as answer I will accept it. I changed the applicaion from 32 bit to 64 and it works

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have installed 64 bit version of MS Access, as you should, since a Windows Server 2012 machine is almost certain 64bit. However you Console App.is build as 32-bit.
Try building your application targetting both 32 and 64 bit OS

[image]